# Boost::string_ref find algorithms

Tags: c++, string, boost

I am having some problems figuring out what does the boost library string_ref find function do. I wrote the following program

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    boost::string_ref ref = string("<a>\n1234567\n</a>\n<a>");
    cout << ref.find_first_of("<a>") << endl; // output 12
    cout << ref.find("<a>") << endl; // output 17
}
```

I do not understand why find gives me the last occurence of my pattern and find_last_of does not even make sense at all! Can someone give me some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html):

> Boost.StringRef is an implementation of Jeffrey Yaskin's N3442: string_ref: a **non-owning reference** to a string.

`string_ref` doesn't own anything, just refers to it. So when you write:

```
boost::string_ref ref = string("<a>\n1234567\n</a>\n<a>");
```

that temporary `string` gets destroyed at the end of the line and now you have a dangling reference. Everything else is UB.

Comment: If you had written: `boost::string_ref ref = "<a>\n1234567\n</a>\n<a>";`, you would get consistent answers, since the string literal never "gets destroyed"